# How to connect my RaspBerry Pi directly to my PC using ethernet cable? Don't work

Tags: raspbian, ethernet, headless, connection

I am trying to install\configure RaspBian on my new RaspBerry Pi in headless way.

So I have wrote the RaspBian distro on the SD using the **dd** Linux statment and I am following this tutorial to connect the Raspberry directly to my PC using an ethernet cable.

So after power on the RaspBerry I have the following led turned on: **100**, **LNK**, **FDK** and **PWR**. Is it ok? Can I deduce that the installation is ok?

Then, into Ubuntu on my PC I performed the following operations:

1) I click on the networking icon in the top right, then I go to **Modify Connections**

2) Into **Wired tab** I click on the **Add** button.

3) I used **Shared** as name for the new connection

4) The I go on the **IPv4 settings tab** and I have the following configurations:

[image]

5) So now I want discover the IP address of my RaspBerry and, as the tutorial explain, I perform this command into the shell:

```
grep dnsmasq-dhcp /var/log/syslog
```

But I obtain no result, what am I missing? What could be the problem? How can I solve it?

Tnx

EDIT: this is what I see if I perorm:  **tail /var/log/syslog**

```
May 28 20:42:45 andrea-virtual-machine kernel: [ 2923.477306] e1000: eth0 NIC Link is Down
May 28 20:42:49 andrea-virtual-machine NetworkManager[1136]: <info> (eth0): carrier now ON (device state 100)
May 28 20:42:49 andrea-virtual-machine kernel: [ 2927.480580] e1000: eth0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: None
May 28 20:42:55 andrea-virtual-machine NetworkManager[1136]: <info> (eth0): carrier now OFF (device state 100, deferring action for 4 seconds)
May 28 20:42:55 andrea-virtual-machine kernel: [ 2933.484501] e1000: eth0 NIC Link is Down
May 28 20:42:59 andrea-virtual-machine NetworkManager[1136]: <info> (eth0): carrier now ON (device state 100)
May 28 20:42:59 andrea-virtual-machine kernel: [ 2937.487692] e1000: eth0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: None
```

What it means?

Comment: you should set static IP to both PC and RPI. put the SD card on your PC and edit the fie /media/pc-name/.../etc/network/interfaces and setup static ip

Comment: Your leds are fine. The OK led should blink while booting (indicating SD reads/writes).

Comment: A router would also be easier. Most routers have a way of showing current DHCP leases.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to leave a comment rather than an answer as it is not a full answer to your question, but I don't have enough reputation to comment...

You haven't specified what Ethernet cable you are using, or if you are using a switch or not (your question title suggests that you are not using a switch). Usually when you want to connect directly between two computers you will need a "cross-over" Ethernet cable, or connect both computers to a switch or hub using a "standard" cable. I did a search on if the RaspberryPi will auto-detect, and while someone says it does, post 5, by amyren, on [this page](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=26&t=17680) suggests that it doesn't, and you do need the right cable depending on your setup.

Comment: There is no need a "cross-over" Ethernet cable with most computers these days, as they detect. Most direct connect problems are because the Pi doesn't have an IP, as it can't get to DHCP server.

Answer (score 0):

You have asked a number of related questions, but supply virtually no information about what YOU have done, making it hard to give answers.

Have you actually searched this site for answers to similar problems? We could do this for you and post answers, but it is much better if you do it yourself.

Are you using a router or directly connecting your Pi to the PC? I would guess a router from the leds. If so you should be able to discover the IP address as suggested by @Gerben.

DON"T try to run before you can walk. Don't try to set up sharing (you need to perform some configuration on the Pi - this is easy if you have a monitor and keyboard).

Try `ssh` from your Linux box to the Pi, and work from there.